# Incorrect xml format on recycle view page

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am working on an android app where I populate my recycle view with items from my web server.

Problem, 
I am not too clear what's wrong with my recyclerview, each "item"seems to take an entire screen and I have looked at other XML formats and they seem identical to mine. Yet I have a large margin.
Refer to the pic

XML

Customrow xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_age"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Recyler Fragment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/cointainerDrawerID"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">






        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/drawrList"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>




</RelativeLayout>
```

In the image, you see two items, but instead one below the other..it's on an entirely different page.

[image: Recycler View]

Comment: you will have to give the `CardView` a fixed height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with "layout_height" attribute. Change it to "wrap_content" or simply paste the below code for your item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="16dp"
>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/person_photo"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/person_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/person_age"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
            android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code your items has `android:layout_height="match_parent"`
Changing it to `wrap_content` or some fixed value will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Change android:layout_height="match_parent" of parent linear layout to android:layout_height="wrap_content"

or

use card view as a parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

Recyclerview has a LayoutManager, and you can use it like this :

```
recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
```